# What word is used to describe speech patterns?

Tags: writing, accent

By speech patterns I mean writing out how an accent sounds. The form of writing used to analyze accents and ways of speaking in the past. I was watching The Lighthouse yesterday and I remember hearing that the director studied this type of writing when giving his characters accents. I’ve been trying to remember the word since I watched it. Any enlightenment would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you describe this type of writing any better? At this point I can only guess at what you mean. IPA? Dialect?

Comment: It replaces the regular spelling of the words that the person is saying with a spelling of how it sounds. Sort of like writing “ye” instead of “you.”

Comment: . . . . . .  phonetic symbols ? [International Phonetic Alphabet](http://www.antimoon.com/how/pronunc-soundsipa.htm).

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the word by looking for the video that was talking about how the director studied the dialect. The word I was thinking of was “vernacular.” I found that the way I was describing it was more along the lines of “phonetics.”

Comment: ɔː duː juː miːn ðiː IPA ˈalfəbɛt? :)

Comment: Right. _Vernacular_ just means 'the language as it is spoken (at some time and place)'. If you want to study the **sounds** of speech, the science is Phonetics, as you found. If you want to study the **meaning** of speech, the science is Semantics (or Pragmatics). If you want to study the **arrangement** of speech, the science is Grammar (or Syntax). These are all part of Linguistics; we linguists find that we have to keep these levels separate to talk about them usefully. It's too easy to get confused when you use language to talk about language.